# Subspace and orthogonal complement span whole space even if the form is degenerate?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space over a field $\mathbb{R}$. Let $B\colon V\times V\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a bilinear form.

Assume that $B$ is **degenerate**.

**Q.1** Does $V$ has orthogonal / orthonormal basis?

**Q.2** If $U$ is a subspace of $V$, then is it always true that $U$ and $U^{c}$ (the orthogonal complement of $U$) span whole $V$?

Comment: What would be an orthonormal basis in this case?

Comment: A basis $\{v_1,\cdots, v_n\}$ is orthonormal if $B(v_i,v_j)=\delta_{ij}$.

Comment: So that's impossible to find such if eg $B=0$.

Comment: Yes. So, but "orthogonal" basis exists here. I would like to know whether it (orthogonal basis) always exists?

Comment: OK! I will think in positive direction for Q.2, as per your reply. (I don't know about it.)

Comment: I am not sure, I understand the question correctly, but it seems to me that $Q2$ holds independent of $B$ for finite vectorspaces. Take $x \in V, u \in U$ and call $w = x-u$, then $u + w = x$, now with $u$ and $w$ you can find an $w' = w - u<w,u>/<u,u>$ and $u' = u + u<w,u>/<u,u>$ which lies in $U^{c}$ and $w' + u' = x$.

Comment: Let $W=\{ v\in V; B(v,v)=0\}$. Is this a subspace of $V$? Can we define $\tilde{B}$ on $V/W$ by $\tilde{B}(u+W,v+W)=B(u,v)$?

Comment: $W$ is not a subspace in general.

Answer (score 1):

By definition of a degenerate form, there exists $x\in V$, $x\neq0$, such that $B(x,y)=0$ for all $y\in V$. In particular, if $\{v_1,\ldots,v_n\}$ is a basis of $V$ then $B(x,v_j)=0$ for all $j$. If we assume $B(v_i,v_j)=0$ for $i\neq j$ then this would imply $B(v_j,v_j)=0$ for some $j$. I suppose you could in principle define an orthogonal basis to be one where $B(v_i,v_j)=0$ for $i\neq j$, regardless of whether or not $B(v_j,v_j)=0$, in which case the Gram-Schmidt process would still work.

The second question is true although the sum is not necessarily direct. Take a basis $\{v_1,\ldots,v_k\}$ of $U$, extend to a basis $\{v_1,\ldots,v_n\}$ of $v$, apply Gram-Schmidt to get a basis $\{e_1,\ldots,e_n\}$ of $V$ such that $\{e_1,\ldots,e_k\}$ spans $U$ and $B(e_i,e_j)=0$ for $i\neq j$. If $x=\sum_{j=1}^na_je_j\in V$, then $x=y+z$ where $y=\sum_{j=1}^ka_je_j\in U$ and $z=\sum_{j=k+1}^na_je_j\in U^c$, this last statement following since $B(e_i,e_j)=0$ for all $1\leq i\leq k,k+1\leq j\leq n$. If $x\in U$ is such that $B(x,y)=0$ for all $y\in V$ then $x\in U\cap U^c$.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Now I am understanding "Gram-Schmidt" more clearly. In short (a) orthogonal basis always exists (b) orthonormal basis exists if the form is non-degenerate (c) subspace and orthogonal complement always span whole space. [just rewriting your answer; but let me know whether (a), (b), (c) are "correctly" written.]